# Special char or wildcard in awk field separator

Tags: shell-scripting, awk

Would appreciate to know about the special char or wildcard in the following command:

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | awk -F ' *|:' '/inet addr/{print $4}'
```

What does the code below mean?

```
awk -F ' *|:' '
```

Comment: Did I fully explain that? If so, you can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, which will give you plus 2 to your reputation. Welcome to the site, by the way. Plus 1 for the interesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -F flag (for awk) means to use the following extended regular expression as a **Field separator** Which means it treats any of the characters between the single quotes here: `' *|:'`  as delimiters.

Awk will then print the 4th field that has a match with `inet addr`.

For example: if this were the output for `ifconfig eth0`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 09:00:12:90:e3:e5  
          inet addr:192.168.1.29 Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe70:e3f5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:54071 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:48515 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:22009423 (20.9 MiB)  TX bytes:25690847 (24.5 MiB)
          Interrupt:10 Base address:0xd020
```

It should print out

```
192.168.1.29
```

To break down the regular expression:

```
' *|:'
```

the

```
' *'
```

Means any number of spaces, and the remaining characters have no special meaning, so either of them can be a delimiter. The `*` itself is not a delimiter, it just means any number of the preceding character, a space.

Comment: @ Aaron .. for yeilding the same output i used the below code..


  " ifconfig | grep 'inet addr' | awk {'print $2'} | sed s/.*://"



What does sed s/.*:// means ? i learned it somwhere to clear the matching pattern but did not get the holistic meaning ....
 
->   basically   ".*:"

Answer (score 0):

As you know, `ip command` exists in `/sbin` and `/bin` ,  So if you want to run your script in non-root, You can use the following statement :

```
mohsen@debian:~$ ip addr show eth0 |grep inet |grep -v inet6 | awk '{print $2}' |awk -F/ '{print $1}'
192.168.1.4
```

Comment: That's correct..